# Flux Framework with ie8 support?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, reactjs, flux

Im looking at using the flux pattern yet i'm also required to support ie8*. Thus far Im unclear on if there are any existing flux frameworks which support it or if rolling our own implementation would be the only solution.

- yes IE8 sucks, supporting it is not my decision.

** I realize this question is a little general yet after spending a day on google and npm and finding little info i figure others may benefit from it too.

Answer (score 0):

[fluxxor](https://github.com/BinaryMuse/fluxxor)
 may support ie8 using [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim)